# Property of object in array is reactive when all elements are changed, but not if only some are changed

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-tables-2

I have this selectAllToggle function, which reactively selects or deselects all elements in the array.  Reactively in that when the selectButton is used, all the checkboxes in the browser show selected or deselected.

The problem arise when one or more (but not all) checkboxes were manually selected. If any checkboxes are selected, the selectButtonName changes to "Deselect All", and when pressed, I want it to deselect all.
The code I have correctly updates the array, in that it sets the 'selected' property to false for every student in the array, but the reactivity of it doesn't work - the tick boxes of the students that were selected manually, remain ticked in the browser.

```
selectAllToggle: function(key, row, $event) {
    var setTo = false;
    var newname = "Select All";
    if (this.selectButtonName === "Select All") {
        setTo = true;
        newname = "Deselect All";
    }
    if (this.selectButtonName === "Deselect All") {
        setTo = false;
        newname = "Select All";
    }

    if (this.students.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.students.length; i++) {
            this.students[i]['selected'] = setTo;
        }
    }
    this.selectButtonName = newname;
    
    console.log(this.students);    //shows the correct 'selected' state for all
},
```

The view looks like this (using vue-tables-2)

```
<v-client-table 
   v-if="gridReady" 
   v-model.sync="students" 
   :columns="gridcolumns" 
   :options="gridoptions"
   ref="grid">

<input type="checkbox" 
    slot="selected" 
    slot-scope="{row, update}" 
    v-model="row.selected"
    @change="selectStudent('select', row, $event)">

</v-client-table>
```

What can I do to make this function reactive?

Comment: Perhaps the student objects aren't being observed by Vue. How are you loading the student data? Is it declared upfront in the `data` property? Does each student object have a `selected` property *before* you assigned it to data (good) or did you add those properties later (bad)?

Comment: student data is declared upfront in the data property, but doesn't have a selected property when loaded from the back end - it is added afterwards in the vue js.   I can add this property in the back end - seems like an good suggestion, so will comment here to say if it worked

Comment: @DecadeMoon I now have selected = false for every student as loaded from the back end, and still have the same problem.  But this isn't quite what you suggested I think.  Because the order of things (as I understand it) is: data property > mounted > refreshGrid (which loads student data from back end).   The only way to have it in the data property from the beginning that I can think of, is if students come in as a prop, and then  in the data I have localStudents: this.students.

Comment: The backend shouldn't be polluting the student objects with a `selected` property, this is a frontend-only property. You just have to do in order (1) fetch the student data, (2) loop over each student and add the `selected` property, (3) assign the students array to `this`. Otherwise you need to use [Vue.set](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set).

Comment: @DecadeMoon I tried Vue.set before, possibly used it wrong.  Now I have it working, but what solved it was to also use Vue.set in the selectStudent function, which is what is used when selecting one student at a time.   Thank you - your knowledge really helped me.  I'm ready to accept an answer if you add your comments as one.

Answer (score 0):

For deselecting after one or more element selection, you may use a `computed property` as the snippet below for reactively perform.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    selected: [],
    clientList: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  },
  computed: {
    selectAll: {
      get: function() {
        return this.selected.length > 0 &&
          this.selected.length <= this.clientList.length
      },
      set: function(value) {
        let list = [];
        if (value) {
          this.selected = this.clientList
        } else {
          this.selected = []
        }

      }
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.7/vue.js"></script>

  <div id='app'>
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Client Name</th>
          <th style="width: 10%"><input type="checkbox" v-model="selectAll" /></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(item,index) in clientList">
          <td style="font-weight: bold;width: 75%">{{item}}
          </td>
          <td style="width: 25%">
            <input type="checkbox" :value="item" v-model="selected" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```